# Request to undelete a question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete, undeleted-questions

I like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167943/retrieving-path-of-referrer-in-django-template) (BTW, [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qOoRuWwNQTkJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45167943/retrieving-path-of-referrer-in-django-template%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in) it is from the Google cache), but it was deleted recently by the OP. I don't see its duplicate.

I don't have enough reputation to undelete. Is there a way to *request* the community to undelete it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would like to get it undeleted other than _I like this question_ ? Maybe search for what exactly you are looking for.. Or form your own _good_ question..

Comment: The reason is that I need an answer to that question and I don't find it anywhere else. Yes, asking on my own is the fallback alternative. I wanted to know if I can also request undelete for a question.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier for you to ask the question again yourself?

Comment: From what I see in the google cache version, the question was a potential duplicate. If you think the linked question misses something important you should ask a new question that insists on that matter. Even better, you can reference this question to prevent people from answering it again and focus on what is lacking.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick thoughts. Have asked this question again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385583/getting-path-of-previous-url-from-template) now focussing on what I need that is not asked/answered in other posts

Comment: It's not clear why such a useful question would get so many downvotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you *can* request that a deleted question be undeleted.

One way of doing this is by asking on Meta, like you've done here, which will get the attention of trusted community members who can cast undelete votes. Ultimately, if the community agrees with you, the question will be undeleted. However, when you do this, it is *strongly* advised to include a justification for undeleting the question. You failed to do that here—you just said that you "like" the question, without telling us *why* you liked it, much less why you liking something is cause to undelete it.

Similarly, instead of Meta, you could ask in a chat room. Everything else is the same. I'd prefer this type of thing be handled via Meta.

An alternative way of getting a deleted question restored is by flagging it for moderator attention, using a custom flag to plead your case for undeletion. Obviously, using this route, it is even more crucial that you make a strong, clear case for having the question undeleted, because you're asking a moderator to use their unilateral powers to overrule another user's wishes. They won't do this lightly, and in fact are not likely to do it at all unless the question has *obvious* value. This one didn't. (Again, I'd recommend that this type of thing be handled via Meta.)

That explains what can be done. The contributor license agreement grants an irrevocable right to Stack Overflow to display the content as they see fit, so we are technically within our rights to undelete anything.

That said, the situations where this is actually justified are, in my opinion, quite rare. In fact, I can't imagine ever voting to undelete a question that had not received any answers or upvotes. Why not? Well, I think an individual contributor should have the right to delete their content unless that right is overridden by another more compelling concern. An example of a more compelling concern would be the effort put in by the answerer(s) and the information that is being lost by deleting it.

In this case, there was nothing worth salvaging. Just a short, incomplete-looking question with no upvotes, no answers, and only a tiny number of views. We haven't lost anything by allowing that one to be deleted.

If you have a question of your own, then you should ask a new question. You did the right thing by [reposting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385583/getting-path-of-previous-url-from-template), and that allowed you to write a *better* question, with more information. It cannot be a "duplicate" of a question that has been deleted! If there's something from the other question that you want to reuse, then you can still give credit to the author, by name, for whatever it is you want to use in your own question.

Comment: I tried to flag my deleted question and it got declined because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". I still need my question answered even though Roomba decided to delete it.