# After I improve a moderator closed and deleted question, should I ask for it to be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-undelete

I noticed some strange activity on my reputation, and I was able to track it down to a question I had answered that was closed and then sometime later deleted.

Because of the closure reason, I spent some time improving the question.

- This is what it was [before](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37224004/1)
- And this is what it is [now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224004/circular-linked-list-only-has-one-element-after-inserting-two)

Since the question was deleted by a moderator, I cannot vote to undelete it (which makes total sense).

But should I try to ask at all? Some other related questions I have seen regarding community deleted questions have recommended leaving things pat. Instead, attempt to create a new self-answered question with the improved version.

Is that the recommendation for this specific question? Or should I flag and make a request for it to be undeleted?

Comment: It seems strange that it's deleted by a moderator. I wonder if it's a copyright issue.

Comment: @ayhan it was deleted as part of the burnination of the [tag:circular] tag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367803/the-circular-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/request-to-undelete-a-question#354045 and many, many more ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If a moderator has closed/deleted a question, you can always flag the post asking for it to be reopened/undeleted. From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions):

> If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.

A moderator will then view your flag, and decide to take action. Do not go to recreate the question answer pair.

For that particular question, after your nice edit, it now does have a valid MCVE, therefore I have undeleted it. Thank you for the edit.

Comment: I question whether it should have been deleted in the first place. Generally questions should only be deleted if they are actively harmful to the site.

Comment: @corsiKa It was deleted as part of the on going burnination of [circular] tag. We delete all the off topic posts. That question as such did not have a MCVE originally, for which it was closed, and later deleted.

Comment: So a post that doesn't have an MCVE is off-topic? I must have missed the memo.

Comment: @corsiKa: It is the 4th option within *Closing > Off-Topic*:
Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jhx Yes, but there is a difference between "Wow, this question is very close, you just need to clean up the code to get rid of the excess code" and "this question should be deleted for being off topic" - like, miles of difference. The OP has desired behavior, a problem statement and honestly a fairly short piece of code (less than 80 lines) to reproduce the problem. The letter of the law may say "shortest code" but the spirit of the law was definitely fulfilled by the OP. And further, questions with upvoted answers should *almost never* be deleted. Lots of reasons to not delete that question.

Comment: @corsiKa: Yeah, very strange. I can *just barely* rationalize (and even then, not quite, given as you said it has an upvoted answer) deleting the question if it had been closed back in '16 when it was first asked and since abandoned, but *it wasn't even closed before the burnination took place*. If the question had any MCVE issues at all, not enough people ever kicked up a fuss about it over the last 2 and a half years for it to be closed.

Comment: @corsiKa: I too felt the question just needed a little massaging to avoid closure, which is why I went ahead and put the effort in to make the edit. I didn't think it would be productive to challenge the premise of the deletion, since I am not really tuned into what moderators do, or how they do it.

Comment: Well, I guess I was a bit overzealous when I deleted it. I have written down the usual approach I use when deleting a post because of burnination [in this chat conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44259798#44259798). It was borderline for sure, but looking at the post itself didn't seem like it would be really helpful (negative scored, low number of votes on the question and answer, answer, not accepted, no updates since the day of creation, 50 views on the post, etc). Therefore I deleted the post.