# Undelete a question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

Following the answers on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/request-to-undelete-a-question), I would like to request [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959951/find-the-most-optimal-way-in-a-graph-starting-and-ending-at-the-same-vertex/74975023#74975023) to be undeleted.

I think the question had value; from what I can judge, my post just did answer it and ultimately, a couple of people had commented (I cannot see the comments anymore), and I would be more than happy to receive feedback from them too.

Really, I cannot see a "good" reason to delete it, except maybe if what I answered was a university assignment that the author wanted to make difficult to find.

### Edition:

Now, I would like to add a reply to the answer below.
It looks to me you are explaining why I should not have answered this question in the first place, rather than whether or not it is worth undeleting, and why.

Let me start with it and sorry for the technical details:

1. **About the question being unclear or lacking debugging details** (to be compared with the [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385583/getting-path-of-previous-url-from-template) from Cody Gray's answer in the other meta question):
   If I compare, I agree there is missing information.
   However, this is bound to happen when discussing algorithms, especially on a notoriously complicated topic like graph theory.
   There can really be only 1 reason for an infinite loop to happen when walking nodes in a finite graph and that is visiting the same nodes over and over again. I thought and still think it did not really need more details about any root cause. In hindsight, I believe that would have been useless at best, and distracting at worst.
2. **About the question needing more focus.**
   I understand what you mean but I see this as a spectrum of complexity rather than as a yes/no type of thing.
   Imagine the question was "I want to prove Collatz conjecture (3N+1)", that I somehow know how to do it but I only do "figuring out what part of the process actually causes difficulty".
   Obviously, the question is super hard (needless to say nobody on earth knows how yet), so hard in fact I do not see any amount of explanation except the complete proof could be useful...
   So between the easy and super complex questions, where is the limit between `it is fine to break it down and only answer the specific issue` and `anything except the full answer is going to be useless`?
   I agree with your point, I just place the limit elsewhere.
   For the deleted question, there was actually another answer (see [this link](https://godbolt.org/z/YM5Pbnxrz) in a comment from someone else). However, I checked it myself and what appeared to be an obvious solution at first (including to me) was flawed.
   At the end of the day, I figured everything was to be scrapped for a less obvious, more robust solution which does not use weights at all.

**Conclusion**: Only my opinion but there is more value in answering questions about a whole algorithm compared to the other more focused question I linked above.
I agree with the points raised by Karl Knechtel except for how high the bar that must be cleared should be. Even for me, there are obviously questions that do not clear it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623153/how-to-highlight-selected-items-in-qdommodel-xml-treeview#comment131727828_74623153)); this one does.

---

Now, back to the main point and Cody Gray's criteria + 1 more:

1. **The information that is being lost by deleting it**
   As I said above, the problem is probably not a novel one but also is not among the most common ones: similar but not quite identical to the travelling salesman problem, not about finding the minimum path between 2 nodes, ...
   Also, I do believe my solution is worth keeping (and I wish it was kept accessible to other people to comment on that point) because it was not completely obvious.
2. **The effort put in by the answerer(s)**:
   Needless to say, I have spent a few hours on this...
3. **About deleting messages** (discussed in [this other meta-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270274/you-have-deleted-5-answers-today-further-deletes-are-blocked)):
   Stack overflow blocks people from deleting everything because of rage-quitting the site. A license creates a balance of powers between the site and contributors, fair enough.
   However, I would like to appeal that **my** post is being deleted by 1 other person, alone, along with his own question, not even by admins after collecting votes. That removes the chance for me to get feedback on my code and **that** does not look balanced to me...

Set aside my possibly helping a student cheating (sic...), can I ask again if the question/answer is worth undeleting? Or alternatively, if it is worth reposting?
After all, if I am the only one thinking it was worth anything... :-)

Comment: "It was deleted 2 hours ago by the post author."... Just don't answer homework assignments in the future - such authors are eager to hide the fact someone else wrote the code.

Comment: Well... it was not obvious to me that was an assignment, still isn't BTW even if I find it suspicious now, but I'll try to be careful in the future.

Comment: I haven't evaluated your answer in detail and am not familiar with C++, so didn't actually upvote your answer. However, your answer did appear to be something that's likely to have value, so I undeleted it. If someone upvotes your answer, then the question author won't be able to delete the question. In a situation where the question author deletes a question with an answer that has value, it's reasonable to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request undeletion of the question.

Answer (score 13):

> except maybe if what I answered was a university assignment that the author wanted to make difficult to find.

This seems highly likely.

But also, in general please keep in mind that Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be *specific*. The goal here seems to be to implement an entire algorithm, and the question seems to be about debugging an entire code dump for that algorithm. It is OP's responsibility, before posting, to attempt debugging, isolate a specific part of the code which malfunctions, explicitly state and explain the expected and actual behaviour of that code, and ask a clear question.

If I had seen this question when it was asked, I would absolutely have voted to close. As a request for debugging help, it fails on multiple counts:

- It is **unclear**, because "Unfortunately, I got nowhere, because I always enter some infinite loops." does not describe a *specific* problem;
- It **lacks debugging details**, because OP's example is neither **minimal** (we should only see the member functions that will be involved in creating a simple graph for testing and the attempt at actually implementing the algorithm) nor **complete** (we should see hard-coded example input that causes the aforementioned infinite-loop problem, along with OP's analysis of *where* the infinite loop occurs).

It's important to note that we don't provide a debugging service here. While there is a "needs debugging details" closure reason, I think it is misnamed. In my experience, when the *expected* debugging effort has been put in, a question can still remain, and it can be a simple question, and it *can* be an excellent question in spite of its simplicity; but it is **not a debugging question any more**. Instead, it is a conceptual question about why a specific code construct works in a certain way (as opposed to a debugging question, which is about *identifying* which code construct did something unexpected, and about *making expectations explicit*).

A proper analysis from OP would involve figuring out ahead of time: Which functions participate in the loop? Is it looping due to an unterminated `while`, or from unbounded recursion? In the `while` case, for example, what is the loop condition? What part of the code is intended to cause the condition to be broken, and how? What appears to be happening instead when that code runs?).

After figuring these things out, OP would then be expected to simplify and pinpoint the problem as much as possible (for example, is there some point in the process where `getSuccessors` returns an unexpected value? Is the attempt at graph traversal, for example, bouncing back and forth between two nodes, without accounting for travel time? Is it moving in a loop without accounting for travel time? Is it perhaps **ignoring** the fact that there is no travel time left? If the algorithm is recursive, do some of the recursive branches appear to share state where they are intended not to?

---

On the other hand, if understood as a **how-to** request (this might be more likely), the question fails due to **needing more focus**. It is essentially asking for the entire algorithm, at both conceptual and code levels. We don't provide that service, either. OP is responsible for trying to break the problem down into logical steps, and figuring out what part of the process actually causes difficulty. For example: moving back and forth between two nodes should take time, and accounting for that time should eventually cause it to run out. Perhaps that would be sufficient to prevent infinite loops?